# What is awk '{ print $2; }' doing exactly?

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting

I would like to know what is this statement doing exactly, especially the `awk` part.

```
ps aux | grep 'sidekiq 5' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2; }' | xargs kill -${2:-'TERM'}
```

I know the entire pipeline is supposed to kill `sidekiq` processes.

Comment: Are you asking about the entire pipeline or the `awk` part only?

Comment: I would like to understand the entire pipeline specially the awk part.

Comment: Note: `pkill` may be able to replace this whole pipeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `ps aux` lists all processes.
- `grep 'sidekiq 5'` only displays those lines from the list that contain the string "sidekiq 5".
- `grep -v grep` removes those lines that contain the string "grep". This is done so that the `grep` process from the previous pipeline stage is filtered out.
- `awk '{ print $2; }'` prints the second field of each line. This field happens to be the process ID from the `ps aux` output.
- `xargs kill -${2:-'TERM'}` takes the process IDs from the selected sidekiq processes and feeds them as arguments to a `kill` command. The signal is either $2 or, if $2 is not defined, SIGTERM.

Comment: Using `grep '[s]idekiq 5'` will make `grep -v grep` unnecessary, because the `[s]idekiq 5` expression matches `sidekiq 5` but doesn't match the expression itself. It's an old trick.

Comment: Yes, one encounters this trick often.  Thanks for pointing it out. Slightly advanced; beginners should first study the longer but easier to understand pipeline.